Flutter Error: Failed assertion: line 5882 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true. When Reopening a Page
I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter application where I get the following error when trying to reopen a page for the second time
even when I on the RoomViewBloc  and make hot reload make same error:
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Navigator-[LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#b519d](dirty, dependencies: [HeroControllerScope, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: NavigatorState#516c8(tickers: tracking 0 tickers)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5882 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.yml

The relevant error-causing widget was:
    MaterialApp MaterialApp:file:///C:/flutter_app/lklk-live/lib/main.dart:194:14

This error occurs when I try to reopen the RoomViewBloc page. The first time opening the page works correctly, but subsequent attempts result in the error.
Here is the relevant code for the RoomViewBloc page:
class RoomViewBloc extends StatefulWidget {
  const RoomViewBloc({
    super.key,
    required this.roomId,
    required this.roomCubit,
    this.pass,
    required this.userCubit,
  });

  final int roomId;
  final RoomCubit roomCubit;
  final String? pass;
  final UserCubit userCubit;

  @override
  State<RoomViewBloc> createState() => _RoomViewBlocState();
}

class _RoomViewBlocState extends State<RoomViewBloc> {
  late CallCubit _callCubit;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WakelockPlus.enable();
    _callCubit = context.read<CallCubit>();
    widget.roomCubit.fetchRoomById(widget.roomId, widget.pass);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _callCubit.endCallFull();
    WakelockPlus.disable();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      onPopInvoked: (canPop) async {
        if (mounted) {
          await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: AppColors.transparent,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  _buildActionButton(
                    context: context,
                    label: "Minimize",
                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.compress,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (!Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
                        return;
                      }
                      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));

                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => HomeView(
                          userCubit: widget.userCubit,
                          roomCubit: widget.roomCubit,
                        ),
                      ),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                    );
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  _buildActionButton(
                    context: context,
                    label: "Exit",
                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.xmark,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // End the call
                      // _callCubit.endCall();
 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => HomeView(
                          userCubit: widget.userCubit,
                          roomCubit: widget.roomCubit,
                        ),
                      ),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                    );
                      // if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                      //   Navigator.pop(context);
                      // }

                      // await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));

                      // if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                      //   Navigator.pop(context);
                      // }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      canPop: false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: BlocConsumer<RoomCubit, RoomCubitState>(
          listener: (BuildContext context, RoomCubitState state) {
            if (state is RoomCubitRoomUpdated) {
              setState(() {
                widget.roomCubit.fetchRoomById(widget.roomId, widget.pass);
              });
            } else if (state is RoomCubitRoomLoaded) {
              setState(() {});
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is RoomCubitRoomLoaded) {
              final isMinimized = _callCubit.state.isMinimized;
              if (!isMinimized) {
                log('call isMinimized == false');
                _callCubit.startCall(
                    widget.userCubit, widget.roomCubit, state.room.img);
                _callCubit.loginRoom(
                  widget.userCubit,
                  widget.roomCubit,
                  state.room.id.toString(),
                  widget.userCubit.user!.iduser == state.room.owner
                      ? ZegoLiveAudioRoomRole.host
                      : ZegoLiveAudioRoomRole.audience,
                );
              } else {
                log('call isMinimized == true');
              }
              return _buildRoomView(context, state);
            } else {
              return const SizedBox();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRoomView(BuildContext context, RoomCubitRoomLoaded state) {
    final roomMessagesCubit = BlocProvider.of<RoomMessagesCubit>(context);
    final double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Stack(
      children: [
        BackgroundImageWidget(
          backgroundImage: state.room.background,
        ),
        RoomViewBody(
          userCubit: widget.userCubit,
          room: state.room,
          roomCubit: widget.roomCubit,
          roomMessagesCubit: roomMessagesCubit,
          users: state.users,
          bannedUsers: state.bannedUser,
          role: widget.userCubit.user!.iduser == state.room.owner
              ? ZegoLiveAudioRoomRole.host
              : ZegoLiveAudioRoomRole.audience,
        ),
        BlocBuilder<IsActiveGiftsCubit, bool>(
          builder: (context, isActiveGifts) {
            if (isActiveGifts) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: h / 4,
                    child: TopBarSection(
                      roomCubit: widget.roomCubit,
                      userCubit: widget.userCubit,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(child: GiftsShowSection()),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return const SizedBox();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildActionButton({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String label,
    required VoidCallback onPressed,
    required IconData? icon,
  }) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 90,
            height: 90,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.primary,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Icon(
              icon,
              color: AppColors.white,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

this is when navigation to it
class RoomItemWidgetTitles extends StatefulWidget {
  final RoomEntity room;
  final RoomCubit roomCubit;
  final UserCubit userCubit;

  const RoomItemWidgetTitles({
    super.key,
    required this.room,
    required this.roomCubit,
    required this.userCubit,
  });

  @override
  State<RoomItemWidgetTitles> createState() => _RoomItemWidgetTitlesState();
}

class _RoomItemWidgetTitlesState extends State<RoomItemWidgetTitles> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        String? pass;
        log('room pass : ${widget.room.pass}');
        if (widget.room.pass == null &&
            ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name != 'RoomViewBloc') {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => RoomViewBloc(
                roomCubit: widget.roomCubit,
                roomId: widget.room.id,
                pass: null,
                userCubit: widget.userCubit,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          pass = await showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => const PasswordSetupDialog(),
          );

          if (pass == widget.room.pass && pass != null) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => RoomViewBloc(
                  roomCubit: widget.roomCubit,
                  roomId: widget.room.id,
                  pass: null,
                  userCubit: widget.userCubit,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                content: Text('The Password is Wrong'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      },
      child: Row(
        children: [
          RoomImageWidget(imageUrl: widget.room.img),
          Expanded(child: RoomTitlesWidget(room: widget.room)),
          // const Align(
          //     alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: RoomPointsWidgets()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


this is cubit

class CallState {
  final bool isInCall;
  final bool isMuted;
  final bool isMinimized;
  final String? roomImg;
  CallState(
      {required this.isInCall,
      required this.isMuted,
      required this.isMinimized,
      this.roomImg});
}

class CallCubit extends Cubit<CallState> {
  List<StreamSubscription> subscriptions = [];
  String? currentRequestID;
  ValueNotifier<bool> isApplyStateNoti = ValueNotifier(false);
  final zimService = ZEGOSDKManager().zimService;
  final expressService = ZEGOSDKManager().expressService;
  String? img;

  CallCubit()
      : super(CallState(
            isInCall: false,
            isMuted: false,
            isMinimized: false,
            roomImg: null));

  // void startCall(
  //     UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit, String? roomImg) async {
  //       log('Call start call --------------');
  //   requestMicrophonePermission(userCubit, roomCubit);
  //   _initializeSubscriptions(userCubit, roomCubit);
  //   img = roomImg;
  //   emit(CallState(
  //       isInCall: true, isMuted: false, isMinimized: false, roomImg: roomImg));
  // }
  void startCall(
      UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit, String? roomImg) async {
    log('Call start call --------------');

    // Ensure room scenario is set before login
    await expressService.setRoomScenario(ZegoScenario.General);

    // Check if already in a room and log out if necessary
    if (state.isInCall) {
      logoutRoom();
    }

    requestMicrophonePermission(userCubit, roomCubit);
    _initializeSubscriptions(userCubit, roomCubit);
    img = roomImg;
    emit(CallState(
        isInCall: true, isMuted: false, isMinimized: false, roomImg: roomImg));
  }

  void endCall() {
    log('Call end call --------------');

    // cancelSubscriptions();
    // logoutRoom();
    emit(CallState(
        isInCall: false, isMuted: false, isMinimized: false, roomImg: null));
  }
  void endCallFull() {
    log('Call end call --------------');

    cancelSubscriptions();
    logoutRoom();
    emit(CallState(
        isInCall: false, isMuted: false, isMinimized: false, roomImg: null));
  }
  void toggleMute() {
    log('Call toggleMute call --------------');

    muteAllSpeaker(state.isMuted);
    emit(CallState(
        isInCall: state.isInCall,
        isMuted: !state.isMuted,
        isMinimized: state.isMinimized,
        roomImg: img));
  }

  void toggleMinimize() {
    log('Call toggleMinimize call --------------');

    emit(CallState(
        isInCall: state.isInCall,
        isMuted: state.isMuted,
        isMinimized: !state.isMinimized,
        roomImg: img));
  }

  void toggleMinimizeTrue() {
    log('Call toggleMinimizeTrue call --------------');

    emit(CallState(
        isInCall: state.isInCall, isMuted: state.isMuted, isMinimized: true));
  }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Future<List<ZIMMessageSentResult>> muteAllSpeaker(bool isMute) async {
    final messageType =
        isMute ? RoomCommandType.muteSpeaker : RoomCommandType.unMuteSpeaker;

    List<ZIMMessageSentResult> results = [];

    for (final element in ZegoLiveAudioRoomManager().seatList) {
      final commandMap = {
        'room_command_type': messageType,
        'receiver_id': element.currentUser.value?.userID
      };

      // Send the room command for each user
      final result = await ZEGOSDKManager()
          .zimService
          .sendRoomCommand(jsonEncode(commandMap));

      // Store the result in the list
      results.add(result);
    }

    // Return the list of results for all commands sent
    return results;
  }

  Future<void> requestMicrophonePermission(
      UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit) async {
    final status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      log('Microphone permission is required');
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeView(
            userCubit: userCubit,
            roomCubit: roomCubit,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void _initializeSubscriptions(UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit) {
    subscriptions.addAll([
      expressService.roomStateChangedStreamCtrl.stream.listen(
          (event) => onExpressRoomStateChanged(event, userCubit, roomCubit)),
      zimService.roomStateChangedStreamCtrl.stream.listen(
          (event) => onZIMRoomStateChanged(event, userCubit, roomCubit)),
      zimService.connectionStateStreamCtrl.stream.listen(
          (event) => onZIMConnectionStateChanged(event, userCubit, roomCubit)),
      zimService.onInComingRoomRequestStreamCtrl.stream
          .listen(onInComingRoomRequest),
      zimService.onOutgoingRoomRequestAcceptedStreamCtrl.stream
          .listen(onOutgoingRoomRequestAccepted),
      zimService.onOutgoingRoomRequestRejectedStreamCtrl.stream
          .listen(onOutgoingRoomRequestRejected),
      zimService.onRoomCommandReceivedEventStreamCtrl.stream
          .listen(onRoomCommandReceived),
    ]);
  }

  void cancelSubscriptions() {
    log('Call cancelSubscriptions call --------------');

    for (final subscription in subscriptions) {
      subscription.cancel();
    }
  }

  Future<void> loginRoom(UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit,
      String roomID, ZegoLiveAudioRoomRole role) async {
    // Ensure we are not logged into another room
    if (state.isInCall) {
      log('Already in a room, logging out first...');
      logoutRoom();
    }

    final token =
        kIsWeb ? await AuthService.getTokenFromSharedPreferences() : null;
    ZegoLiveAudioRoomManager()
        .loginRoom(roomID, role, token: token)
        .then((result) {
      if (result.errorCode == 0) {
        // hostTakeSeat();
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          navigatorKey.currentContext!,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomeView(
              userCubit: userCubit,
              roomCubit: roomCubit,
            ),
          ),
        );
        log('Login room failed: ${result.errorCode}');
      }
    });
  }
  // void loginRoom(UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit, String roomID,
  //     ZegoLiveAudioRoomRole role) async {
  //   final token =
  //       kIsWeb ? await AuthService.getTokenFromSharedPreferences() : null;
  //   ZegoLiveAudioRoomManager()
  //       .loginRoom(roomID, role, token: token)
  //       .then((result) {
  //     if (result.errorCode == 0) {
  //       // hostTakeSeat();
  //     } else {
  //       Navigator.pushReplacement(
  //         navigatorKey.currentContext!,
  //         MaterialPageRoute(
  //           builder: (context) => HomeView(
  //             userCubit: userCubit,
  //             roomCubit: roomCubit,
  //           ),
  //         ),
  //       );
  //       log('Login room failed: ${result.errorCode}');
  //     }
  //   });
  // }

  void onRoomCommandReceived(OnRoomCommandReceivedEvent event) {
    log('onRoomCommandReceived $event');
    final Map<String, dynamic> messageMap = jsonDecode(event.command);
    if (messageMap.keys.contains('room_command_type')) {
      final type = messageMap['room_command_type'];
      final receiverID = messageMap['receiver_id'];
      if (receiverID == ZEGOSDKManager().currentUser!.userID) {
        if (type == RoomCommandType.muteSpeaker) {
          log('You have been muted by the host');
          ZEGOSDKManager().expressService.turnMicrophoneOn(false);
        } else if (type == RoomCommandType.unMuteSpeaker) {
          log('You have been unmuted by the host');
          ZEGOSDKManager().expressService.turnMicrophoneOn(true);
        } else if (type == RoomCommandType.kickOutRoom) {
          logoutRoom();
          // Navigator.pop(navigatorKey.currentContext!);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void logoutRoom() {
    log('Call logoutRoom call --------------');

    ZEGOSDKManager().logoutRoom();
  }

  void onInComingRoomRequestCancelled(
      OnInComingRoomRequestCancelledEvent event) {}

  void onInComingRoomRequestTimeOut() {}

  void onExpressRoomStateChanged(
      ZegoRoomStateEvent event, UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit) {
    log('AudioRoomPage:onExpressRoomStateChanged: $event');
    if (event.errorCode != 0) {
      log('onExpressRoomStateChanged: reason:${event.reason.name}, errorCode:${event.errorCode}');
    }

    if ((event.reason == ZegoRoomStateChangedReason.KickOut) ||
        (event.reason == ZegoRoomStateChangedReason.ReconnectFailed) ||
        (event.reason == ZegoRoomStateChangedReason.LoginFailed)) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeView(
            userCubit: userCubit,
            roomCubit: roomCubit,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void onZIMRoomStateChanged(ZIMServiceRoomStateChangedEvent event,
      UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit) {
    log('AudioRoomPage:onZIMRoomStateChanged: $event');
    if ((event.event != ZIMRoomEvent.success) &&
        (event.state != ZIMRoomState.connected)) {
      log('onZIMRoomStateChanged: $event');
    }
    if (event.state == ZIMRoomState.disconnected) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeView(
            userCubit: userCubit,
            roomCubit: roomCubit,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void onZIMConnectionStateChanged(ZIMServiceConnectionStateChangedEvent event,
      UserCubit userCubit, RoomCubit roomCubit) {
    log('AudioRoomPage:onZIMConnectionStateChanged: $event');
    if (event.state == ZIMConnectionState.disconnected) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeView(
            userCubit: userCubit,
            roomCubit: roomCubit,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void onInComingRoomRequest(OnInComingRoomRequestReceivedEvent event) {}

  void onOutgoingRoomRequestRejected(OnOutgoingRoomRequestRejectedEvent event) {
    isApplyStateNoti.value = false;
    currentRequestID = null;
  }

  void onOutgoingRoomRequestAccepted(OnOutgoingRoomRequestAcceptedEvent event) {
    isApplyStateNoti.value = false;
    for (final seat in ZegoLiveAudioRoomManager().seatList) {
      if (seat.currentUser.value == null) {
        ZegoLiveAudioRoomManager().takeSeat(seat.seatIndex).then((result) {
          if (navigatorKey.currentContext!.mounted &&
              ((result == null) ||
                  result.errorKeys
                      .contains(ZEGOSDKManager().currentUser!.userID))) {
            log('take seat failed: $result');
          }
        }).catchError((error) {
          log('take seat failed: $error');
        });

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}


this is main
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Bloc.observer = SimpleBlocObserver();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<RoomCubit>(
            create: (context) => RoomCubit(
                // GoogleSignInUseCase(),
                // AuthApiClient(),
                )),
        BlocProvider<RoomMessagesCubit>(
            lazy: true, create: (context) => RoomMessagesCubit()),

        BlocProvider<UserCubit>(
            create: (context) => UserCubit(
                  GoogleSignInUseCase(),
                  AuthApiClient(),
                )),
        BlocProvider<RelationCubit>(
            lazy: true, create: (context) => RelationCubit()),
        BlocProvider<FreindCubit>(
            lazy: true, create: (context) => FreindCubit()),
        BlocProvider<FreindProgressCubit>(
            lazy: true, create: (context) => FreindProgressCubit()), //
        BlocProvider<RelationProgressCubit>(
            lazy: true, create: (context) => RelationProgressCubit()),

        BlocProvider<MessageCubit>(create: (context) => MessageCubit()),
        BlocProvider<MessageProgressCubitCubit>(
            lazy: true, create: (context) => MessageProgressCubitCubit()),
        BlocProvider<DiamondCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => DiamondCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<PostChargerCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => PostChargerCubit(),
        ), //,

        BlocProvider<PostCenterCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => PostCenterCubit(),
        ), //HomeMessageCubit,
        BlocProvider<HomeMessageCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => HomeMessageCubit(),
        ), //HomeMessageCubit
        BlocProvider<JoinToWakalaCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => JoinToWakalaCubit(),
        ), //,
        BlocProvider<OutFromWakalaCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => OutFromWakalaCubit(),
        ), //
        BlocProvider<ElementsCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => ElementsCubit(),
        ), //
        BlocProvider<BuyItemCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => BuyItemCubit(),
        ), //,
        BlocProvider<FetchElementsCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => FetchElementsCubit(),
        ), //EmojiCubit,
        BlocProvider<EmojiCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => EmojiCubit(),
        ), //EmojiCubit,
        BlocProvider<EmojiPrivateCubit>(
          lazy: true,
          create: (context) => EmojiPrivateCubit(),
        ), //EmojiCubit,

        BlocProvider<GiftsShowCubit>(
          create: (context) => GiftsShowCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        //DisableElementCubit,

        BlocProvider<TopBarRoomCubit>(
          create: (context) => TopBarRoomCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider<BuySvipCubit>(
          create: (context) => BuySvipCubit(Dio()),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider<TopUsersCubit>(
          create: (context) => TopUsersCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider<TopRoomsCubit>(
          create: (context) => TopRoomsCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider<ShowOrHideVip5Cubit>(
          create: (context) => ShowOrHideVip5Cubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider<AlertCubit>(
          create: (context) => AlertCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider<SearchRoomCubit>(
          create: (context) => SearchRoomCubit(Dio()),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => IsActiveGiftsCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => BannerCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => CodeCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => CallCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => RoomUpdatedCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => RoomsCubit(),
          lazy: true,
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        home: const SplashView(),
        title: AssetsData.appLKLK,
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          fontFamily: AssetsData.kFontRubik,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
            seedColor: AppColors.primary,
            primary: AppColors.primary,
            background: AppColors.white,
            error: AppColors.danger,
          ).copyWith(surface: AppColors.white),
          tabBarTheme: const TabBarTheme(
            labelColor: AppColors.golden,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: AppColors.golden,
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: AppColors.golden,
                width: 2,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


